# How do I get 1 row from set of multiple rows based on a condition in PostgreSQL 10?

Tags: postgresql-10

I have two tables, user and car with below mentioned rows and columns.

Table 1: user

```
id | name
---------
1  | ABC
2  | PQR
3  | XYZ
```

Table 2: car

```
id | user_id | is_serviced
--------------------------
1  |    1    |     0
2  |    1    |     1
3  |    2    |     0
4  |    2    |     0
```

User ABC has two cars - only one car has been serviced.
User PQR has two cars - none of the cars has been serviced.
User XYZ has no cars yet.

I want to fetch records as per below output where I want to display all users who have at least one serviced car.

The query I have (I do not understand what clause to use for my query to get the expected output):

```
SELECT u.user_name,
       CASE WHEN c.is_serviced = true THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS has_serviced_car
FROM "user" u
         LEFT JOIN car c ON c.user_id = u.id;
```

The output of the above query:

```
user_name | has_serviced_car
-----------------------
   ABC    |     No
   ABC    |     Yes
   PQR    |     No
   PQR    |     No
   XYZ    |     No
```

Expected output:

```
user_name | has_serviced_car
-----------------------
   ABC    |     Yes
   PQR    |     No
   XYZ    |     No
```

**Please note that user XYZ has no cars still I need it to be displayed.**

Comment: I would probably go for `WHERE EXISTS` and a subquery looking for serviced cars for that user. That works with cars that haven’t been serviced and not having a car also.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
SELECT u.name            AS user_name,
       CASE
           WHEN u.id IN (SELECT u.id
                         FROM "user" u
                                  LEFT JOIN car c ON u.id = c.user_id
                         WHERE c.is_serviced = true) THEN 'Yes'
           ELSE 'No' END AS has_serviced_car
FROM "user" u
         LEFT JOIN car c ON u.id = c.user_id
GROUP BY user_name, u.id
ORDER BY u.id;
```